# Converting mutableCopy to Swift

Tags: swift, afnetworking

I've found this [guide](http://jslim.net/blog/2014/01/12/afnetworking-2-get-json-on-error/) to receive a HTTP Body, witch contains a JSON formatted error message with AFNetworking 2. The guide is in Objective-C and I'm trying my best too convert it to Swift.

Here's the code I'm trying to convert into Swift:

```
- (id)responseObjectForResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
                           data:(NSData *)data
                          error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error {
    if (![self validateResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response data:data error:error]) {
        if (*error != nil) {
            NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [(*error).userInfo mutableCopy];
            NSError *jsonError;
            // parse to json
            id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];
            // store the value in userInfo if JSON has no error
            if (jsonError == nil) userInfo[JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey] = json;
            NSError *newError = [NSError errorWithDomain:(*error).domain code:(*error).code userInfo:userInfo];
            (*error) = newError;
        }
        return (nil);
    }
    return ([super responseObjectForResponse:response data:data error:error]);
}
```

More specific it's this part there's the problem:

```
NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [(*error).userInfo mutableCopy];
```

This is my current code:

```
class JSONResponseSerializerWithData: AFJSONResponseSerializer {

    let JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey: NSString = "JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey"

    override func responseObjectForResponse(response: NSURLResponse!,
        data: NSData!,
        error: NSErrorPointer) -> AnyObject? {
            if(!self.validateResponse(response as NSHTTPURLResponse, data: data, error: error)) {

                if(error != nil) {
                    // The question.....

                    var jsonError: NSError
                    // parse to json

                    // Missing some returns with AnyObejct...   
                }

            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

How do I convert this line into Swift?
I'm quite new with the Swift / Objective-C language, so there might be a simple solution for it, but I've not been able to find it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the same guide that describes how to parse error message in AFNetworking 2 and here is my implementation in Swift:

```
override func responseObjectForResponse(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSErrorPointer) -> AnyObject! {
        if !self.validateResponse(response as! NSHTTPURLResponse, data: data, error: error) {
            if error != nil {
                var userInfo = error.memory!.userInfo!
                var jsonError:NSError?

                let json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &jsonError)
                userInfo[JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey] = json;
                error.memory = NSError(domain: error.memory!.domain, code: error.memory!.code, userInfo: userInfo)

            }
            return nil
        }

        return super.responseObjectForResponse(response, data: data, error: error)
    }
```

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: It works Michael, I'm using it in my newest app. Try it yourself. Let me know if you have any problems with it...

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do the trick:

```
var userInfo = error.userInfo
```

Comment: important to note that this will work since a Dictionary in swift is a struct which is copied when assigned rather than a class type instance which needs to be copied (with copy()) to get the required result (i.e a copied dictionary)

Comment: @giorashc Ahh! Thanks for pointing that out. Another reason why I should read more on using struct. The only problem I have now is a `'NSErrorPointer' does not have a member named 'userInfo'`. Is that  associated with the Swift conversion or an bug in my code?

Comment: note that error is a double pointer so you need to derefernce it twice to reach the instance. i.e. `*(*error).userInfo`

Comment: Swift [avoids giving you direct access to pointers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_14), so I can't use `*`to access them. `*(*error).userInfo` will not work in this case. A compiler error is given. `'*' is not a prefix unary operator`